# Where can I read Andrés Segovía's original autobiographical manuscript?

Tags: spain, music, biography

I'm reading an autobiography of the celebrated guitarist, [Andrés Segovía](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9s_Segovia) ([worldcat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/andres-segovia-an-autobiography-of-the-years-1893-1920/oclc/2439543)). The book is listed in some places (such as Amazon) as "English/Spanish edition", but the text is only English with a few song lyrics presented side-by-side in English and Spanish. The text credits W. F. O'Brien as the translator, presumably because Segovía wrote in Spanish. As charming as the book is, I want to read his original, untranslated words, but I haven't been able to locate a Spanish edition of the book.

Where can I read Andrés Segovía's original autobiographical manuscript?

Comment: It it possible it was originally written in English? If so, its it also possible it was never actually released in Spanish?

Comment: I guess it's possible, in which case I've completely misunderstood the role of "translator" here. I thought maybe there would be a manuscript in some university collections somewhere or something.

Comment: Hmmm. That is a bit puzzling. It could be that the translator merely translated the songs to English, but it would be a bit weird for the dude to be capable of writing the whole book in English, but not of translating his own songs.